# Cleanup 2014: Tags without tag wikis

Tags: discussion, cleanup, tag-wiki

### what is a tag wiki?

Tag wikis are brief excerpts of information detailing what the tag is about, the kinds of questions that should be asked in a tag, and possibly providing you links to some external resources like the Wikipedia article or official website for whatever the tag is about. (if applicable)

### what makes a good tag wiki?

Clear, concise and original information. Tag wikis are shown in multiple places as follows:

When you hover over a tag, either in the tag list, or on a question, a nice little pop up will appear detailing the Excerpt section from the tag wiki:

> [image]

This same excerpt is displayed at the top of the list of questions when you're browsing questions by tag, with a link to "learn more":

> [image]

The full tag wiki is displayed when you click "learn more":

> [image]

So, a good tag wiki will:

- Concisely state what the tag is about when you hover over a tag
- Give a full description of what the tag is when you click "learn more"
- Detail where you can find more information when you click "learn more"
- Be original - we don't like plagiarism at the best of times, but on tag wikis, **don't do it**. If you want to include a small section of text from a site like Wikipedia, clearly block quote it and attribute it and ensure it's not the only information present in the tag.

Tag wikis should be started using the dictionary method; that is we make the assumption that the user knows what they've just clicked on, so don't reiterate it. This means instead of

> "Minecraft is a game by Mojang where you break blocks and eat cake"

we use

> "A game by Mojang where you break blocks and eat cake"

## what tags need a tag wiki adding?

[Here is a full list of all tags on Ask Ubuntu that do not currently have a complete Tag Wiki entry](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/162861/tags-without-tag-wikis).