# What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Related to http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8171/cleanup-2014-tags-without-tag-wikis.

Obviously there are two schools of thought regarding wiki excepts:

- It should tell what that tag is about; e.g. [drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/drivers)

  > Device driver or software driver program allowing higher-level computer programs to interact with a hardware device.
- It should tell what kind of questions should get this tag; e.g. [server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/server)

  > This is for questions related to Ubuntu Server (As opposed to Ubuntu Desktop), and the Ubuntu Server core, as well as any questions related to installing services and programs on Ubuntu Server

I want your input which form is preferable.

The other related question I found (http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3977/what-makes-a-tag-wiki-good) doesn't focus on the excerpt (although the example given is of the second form).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the wiki excerpt has the main purpose to guide the asker about which tags to choose.

So I'd very much prefer the **second form**, describing what kind of questions should get this tag.

The information what this tag is about (especially important with possibly ambiguous terms) should go into the wiki text itself.